# React native app gets crashed whenever I'm using mapbox

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-android

Hey can anyone help me with react-native and mapbox?
Whenever I'm running the command react-native run-android it first starts the app and immediately the app gets crashed